# javascript regex - replace string stop words

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to write a function that removes specific words from a string.

The below code works ok until the last word of the sentence, as it is not followed by a space that my regex looks for.

How can I capture the last word that is not followed by a space?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cVzx8/2/)

```
function stopwords(input) {

var stop_words = new Array('a', 'about', 'above', 'across');

console.log('IN: ' + input);

stop_words.forEach(function(item) {
    var reg = new RegExp(item +'\\s','gi')

    input = input.replace(reg, "");
});

console.log('OUT: ' + input);
}

stopwords( "this is a test string mentioning the word across and a about");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose I am passing `sea` on word

```
stopwords( "this is a test string sea mentioning the word across and a about");
```

which will cut down `sea` to `se`

```
function stopwords(input) {

  var stop_words = ['a', 'about', 'above', 'across'];

  console.log('IN: ' + input);

  // JavaScript 1.6 array filter
  var filtered  = input.split( /\b/ ).filter( function( v ){
        return stop_words.indexOf( v ) == -1;
  });

  console.log( 'OUT 1 : ' + filtered.join(''));

  stop_words.forEach(function(item) {
      // your old : var reg = new RegExp(item +'\\s','gi');
      var reg = new RegExp(item +'\\b','gi'); // dystroy comment

      input = input.replace(reg, "");
  });

  console.log('OUT 2 : ' + input);
}

stopwords( "this is a test string sea mentioning the word across and a about");
```

which has output

```
IN: this is a test string sea mentioning the word across and a about

OUT 1 : this is  test string sea mentioning the word  and  

OUT 2 : this is  test string se mentioning the word  and
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [word boundary marker](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) :

```
var reg = new RegExp(item +'\\b','gi')
```